# Google Contacts API without HTTPS

Tags: javascript, api, https, google-contacts-api, google-content-api

I would like to import my Google contacts to my web application which is build in JavaScript. I used the [Google Contacts API version 3.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) to do this, but it requires HTTPS permissions. Is there a way to import my Google contacts in a developing environment with HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

*All* requests to the Contacts API must be sent with *https://*.

Sending a GET request to the Contacts API over HTTP will result in a redirect and a POST/PUT/DELETE will result in a 401/403. There is no way around this.

(Your title says "*without* HTTPS" and your question says "with HTTPS". I am assuming the former.)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. But I managed to do contact import with the help of [this site](http://www.9bitstudios.com/2013/05/using-oauth-2-0-for-google-apis/).